# Guarantee of compiler instruction reorderings in C++

Tags: c++

Given is the following function `foo`

```
int x;
void foo()
{
    [...]
    x = 0x1234;
    cv.set();
    [...]
}
```

`cv` is a **non-standard** condition variable, offered by an external API I *have* to use. Which guarantees does the C++ standard give, so I can be sure, that `x` is never written after the condition variable is set.

The condition variable of course uses a memory fence internally, but since due to the implementation being in a different translation unit, the compiler can't know that during the compilation of foo.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `cv.set()` doesn't access `x`, and the language rules say that if it does it must read `0x1234`, so in practice the compiler can't move it past the call.

Comment: @T.C. And it similarly doesn't know that or that `cv` has no memory fence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `cv` is a non-standard condition variable ... Which guarantees does the C++ standard

None. The standard cannot guarantee the behavior of something that by definition is outside of the standard's purview. If `cv` does not (internally) use things the C++ standard recognizes, then the standard cannot talk about their behavior.

You therefore only have the guarantees that the maker of `cv` gives you, as well as those of your implementation.

That being said:

> since due to the implementation being in a different translation unit, the compiler can't know that during the compilation of foo.

If the compiler can't see the implementation of some function, how would the compiler know if it is using a C++ `condition_variable` or a POSIX thing or something else? Or even none of those.

It can't. The compiler can't know that some function call *won't* invoke some standard-defined synchronization mechanism, so the implementation will have to assume that it does and avoid reordering instructions in a way that might violate such a mechanism.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: It's the assumption from the question: "*non-standard condition variable*".

Comment: I meant the "(internally)" part. The question says essentially "cv is in a different TU and uses a memory fence", which means that it is written in terms of things the C++ standard specifies. But your edit clarifies/corrects.

Comment: That perfectly answers my question! I assumed exactly that, especially the last text block is the essurance I needed. Thank you

Comment: Note that even if the compiler cannot know the definition, the linker may know it, and could potentially re-order unless that is disallowed by some other reason (which hopefully exists, otherwise the condition variable would be rather useless).